How to add custom icons for a flutter app with flutter_launcher_icons 0.14.2?
im having trouble including an icon for my app on flutter, instead of showing the png file, is only showing a deep black color
even when the success alert shows up and rebuilding my app in debug mode.
it doesnt show anything at all
my pubspec.yaml:
name: almacen_rq
description: "Una app para tecnicos de HTV Telecomm"
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev
version: 0.1.0

environment:
  sdk: ^3.5.1

dependencies:
  file_picker: ^8.1.2
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  intl: ^0.19.0
  open_file: ^3.5.8
  path_provider: ^2.1.4
  pdf: ^3.11.1
  dropdown_button2: ^2.3.9
  firebase_core: ^3.6.0
  cloud_firestore: ^5.4.4
  firebase_auth: ^5.3.1
  csv: ^6.0.0
  email_validator: '^2.1.17'
  flutter_mailer: ^2.1.2
  image_picker: ^1.1.2
  easy_stepper: ^0.8.5+1
  firebase_messaging: ^15.1.6
  flutter_native_splash: ^2.4.3
  flutter_local_notifications: ^18.0.1
  firebase_storage: ^12.3.7
  responsive_builder: ^0.7.1
  
  

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_lints: ^4.0.0

flutter_native_splash:
  image: "assets/htv_remove.png"
  android: false
  ios: false
  color: "ffffff"
  


  
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - "assets/Captura.PNG"
    - "assets/placeholder.PNG" 
    - "assets/ImagenInnova.png"
    - "assets/htv.jpeg"
    - "assets/nabida.jpeg"
    - "assets/htv_remove.png"
    - "assets/pixelcut-export (5).png"
    - "assets/htvgorro.jpeg"
    - "assets/firmalicclaudia.png"

  


next im executing dart run flutter_launcher_icons  and the output is:
Built flutter_launcher_icons:flutter_launcher_icons.
  ════════════════════════════════════════════
     FLUTTER LAUNCHER ICONS (v0.14.2)
  ════════════════════════════════════════════
• Creating default icons Android
• Adding a new Android launcher icon
• Creating mipmap xml file Android

WARNING: Icons with alpha channel are not allowed in the Apple App Store.
Set "remove_alpha_ios: true" to remove it.

• Overwriting default iOS launcher icon with new icon
No platform provided

✓ Successfully generated launcher icons

so next im deleting my app from my phone and rebuilding in debug mode but is not working at all
am i doing it wrong ? or is there is something that im overlooking

which documentation / tutorial are you using for making this project?
have you include /assets in the pubspec?

do prefer use all assets inventory in pubspec.yaml if your codebase is till small and don't consider high performance

im using flutter launcher icons at this moment, and yes i included some images to my pubspec
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_launcher_icons

i just edit the question, in case you want the whole pubspec, i alr delete the flutter launcher icons part and set back to default icon

use this package
flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.14.2

Try this code:
name: almacen_rq
    description: "Una app para tecnicos de HTV Telecomm"
    publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev
    version: 0.1.0
    
    environment:
      sdk: ^3.5.1
    
    dependencies:
      file_picker: ^8.1.2
      flutter:
        sdk: flutter
      intl: ^0.19.0
      open_file: ^3.5.8
      path_provider: ^2.1.4
      pdf: ^3.11.1
      dropdown_button2: ^2.3.9
      firebase_core: ^3.6.0
      cloud_firestore: ^5.4.4
      firebase_auth: ^5.3.1
      csv: ^6.0.0
      email_validator: '^2.1.17'
      flutter_mailer: ^2.1.2
      image_picker: ^1.1.2
      easy_stepper: ^0.8.5+1
      firebase_messaging: ^15.1.6
      flutter_native_splash: ^2.4.3
      flutter_local_notifications: ^18.0.1
      firebase_storage: ^12.3.7
      responsive_builder: ^0.7.1
      
      
    //Do Some Chnages Here
    dev_dependencies:
      flutter_test:
        sdk: flutter
      flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.14.2
      flutter_lints: ^2.0.0

    flutter_icons:
      android: "launcher_icon"
      ios: true
      remove_alpha_ios: true
      image_path_ios: "assets/app_icon.png" //enter your app icon path..
    
    flutter_native_splash:
      image: "assets/htv_remove.png"
      android: false
      ios: false
      color: "ffffff"
      
    flutter:
      uses-material-design: true
      assets:
        - "assets/Captura.PNG"
        - "assets/placeholder.PNG" 
        - "assets/ImagenInnova.png"
        - "assets/htv.jpeg"
        - "assets/nabida.jpeg"
        - "assets/htv_remove.png"
        - "assets/pixelcut-export (5).png"
        - "assets/htvgorro.jpeg"
        - "assets/firmalicclaudia.png"

After set icon path then execute 2 commands in project terminal..
flutter pub get
flutter pub run flutter_launcher_icons

